# Cakephp Naming convention exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, inflector

I got error while accessing view action of my controller,It may be because of naming conventions.My controller file name is **venues_controller.php** and my model file name is **venue.php**.And DB table name is **venues**.
Venues listing page URL is **domain.com/venues/** , and venue detail page is **domain.com/venue/id-slug** these all are working as expected, the problem is occur when i accessing **domain.com/venues/id-slug**, Kindly give me solution , am new to Cakephp.

These error i've got :

```
#0 /home/public_html/demo/app/controllers/venues_controller.php(25): AppController->beforeFilter()
#1 /home/public_html/demo/core/cake/libs/controller/controller.php(538): VenuesController->beforeFilter()
#2 /home/public_html/demo/core/cake/libs/dispatcher.php(175): Controller->startupProcess()
#3 /home/public_html/demo/core/cake/libs/dispatcher.php(138): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(VenuesController), Object(CakeRequest))
#4 /home/public_html/demo/app/webroot/index.php(114): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest))
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: it is not saying about the errors but files.

Comment: got 404 error.. page not found

Comment: You'll have to show your routes configuration, otherwise people can only shoot in the dark, and that's not very productive. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

`domain.com/venues/` - for index action.

i think the error because of there is no action that matches the slug.

`www.example.com/controller/action/slug` - should work.

Comment: I have tried `www.example.com/venues/view/slug` and `www.example.com/venues/view/` without slug.. i got blank page

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. its a general CRUD actions , i have got only singular/plural issues when view single item.. i want as usual controller name in view action.